# Display content after tweet?

Tags: twitter

simple question but I can't seem to find an answer online. (which would probably imply this isn't possible).

I know content can be shown/hidden from users depending on if the liked the page on Facebook or not.

Can the same thing be achieved via Twitter?

EDIT:
basically, is there a way to sue the Twitter API to make a tweet (by an authenticated user) and get a postback info whether or not the tweet was successfull or the user closed the popup?

Comment: What do you mean? People on twitter either follow or not. Follow = they see it. Not = they don't. People facebook like a page. Like = they `might` see it if the newsfeed algorithm thinks it would interest them. Not like = they likely don't see it, unless all their friends are engaging it.

Comment: I guess you can find informations at https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/friendships/show and analyzing returned data to decide if show or not some informations.

Comment: I have worked with FB API a lot but never with Twitter API, so maybe what I'm looking for is "display the content whether or not current user is a follower"..?

Comment: In twitter you do follow or don't, can block or being blocked, do prefer a tweet or don't. There's not like mechanism. So, as I said, I guess the only way to do what you ask for is looks for friendship between the visitor and a particular account and see if one follow the other, then act according to these information.